# Adding photo in moderncv classic

Tags: moderncv, classics

I would like to create a cv including a photo. I am using the following code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
\usepackage{tabularx}
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=3cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\firstname{Z}
\familyname{L}
\mobile{+1~(000)~47~05}                          
\email{z.l@mail.com}                               
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       


\begin{document}

\vspace*{-5\baselineskip}
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}
\section{Education}
\cventry{1453 -- 1233}{Master of Science in nothing}{University of
    paparia}{}{}{GPA: 3.99/4.00}
\end{document}
```

without the command about adding a photo and the output is the one I would like. However when i put the command \photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}, where picture is the name of the folder which includes my photo, then an error appears

File 'picture' not found. \makecvtitle

The exact output is here[image]
Obviously the file is inside to my latex file. Is there a solution to my problem? Because I would like this format plus my photo.

Comment: Please provide a MWE (minimal working example) following the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952, so that we can better understand the problem you are encountering.

Comment: I've made the edits, please give me feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where picture is the name of the folder which includes my photo, then an error appears

Maybe I misunderstood this. But I think you should have a graphic called picture.jpg or picture.png (in the working directory) side by side to your tex file.

In case your graphic is located in a picture directory inside your working directory it should be

```
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture/graphic-name}
```

Best regards

Comment: Do you mean \photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture.jpg}? (my picture is jpg). There is also an error even with this change.

Comment: the file ending is not needed. I also do think it would prevent the picture beeing included. Simply make sure the picture is located side by side to your *.tex file. Then your code should work fine.
If you really like to have the picture in a separate folder you need to specify the name of the picture in that folder ;-)

Comment: there is some progress @N3m3si5 but the photo is appeared turned to the left. What can I do?

Comment: @T.Karawolf what  do you mean by turned to the left? It is rotated anti clockwise? That would be strange...

Comment: Yes, I fixed it. Sorry for my silly and disturbing questions that ruined your day. Thank you for your invaluable time.

Comment: you did not ruin my day :lol:
well done, good to hear you were able to fix it yourself. Have a nice day